# Timezonesetting not honored, system keeps sitting on timezone

Tags: ubuntu, timezone, date

whatever I try, my system (Ubuntu) stays at BRT time instead of CET. I have tried:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`

and set the timezone to "Europe/Berlin".

date still shows BRT instead of CET or GMT+1. Setting the time with date to the correct local time just changes the clock to be another time in "BRT" zone. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuring `tzdata` specifies the system timezone. Each user may have a different personal setting and this may be the reason why you do not see a change. You can [change the user's timezone setting using his/her `.bashrc` file](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-set-time-zone-per-user-basis/).

If you still do not get the desired result, take a look at the [troubleshooting section](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime#Using%20the%20Command%20Line%20%28terminal%29) in the Ubuntu wiki.

Comment: Thanks, the environmentvaribale did it. I wonder why this happened though.

Comment: Glad it worked!